# How to find if any element of an array is within a range in pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column of arrays in a dataframe and I want to know if any of the elements of the array are within a certain range.
Example:
input:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|dateTimeValue                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2019-11-11T20:08:47.453+0000, 2020-10-15T20:08:47.453+0000, 2021-09-19T20:08:47.453+0000]|
|[2017-11-05T20:08:47.453+0000, 2020-05-05T20:08:47.453+0000, 2021-11-11T20:08:47.453+0000]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The date range of interest is Aug 8, 2018 and Dec 8, 2019.
output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|dateTimeValue                                                                             |includedFlag|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|[2019-11-11T20:08:47.453+0000, 2020-10-15T20:08:47.453+0000, 2021-09-19T20:08:47.453+0000]|True        |
|[2017-11-05T20:08:47.453+0000, 2020-05-05T20:08:47.453+0000, 2021-11-11T20:08:47.453+0000]|False       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

The schema of my dataframe is:

```
root 
|-- dateTimeValue: array (nullable = true) | 
    |-- element: timestamp (containsNull = true)
```

The input can be generated with:

```py
import datetime 
df = spark.createDataFrame([([datetime.datetime(2019,11,11,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2020,10,15,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2021,9,19,20,8,47)],), ([datetime.datetime(2017,11,5,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2020,5,5,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2021,11,11,20,8,47)],)], ['dateTimeValue'])
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
For **Spark 2.4+**:
I found a solution for this that doesn't need exploding the dateTimeValue array:

```
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('includedFlag', f.when(f.expr("exists(dateTimeValue, element -> element between '2018-08-08' and '2019-12-08')"), f.lit(True)).otherwise(f.lit(False)))
)
```

and the output is:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+  
|dateTimeValue                                                  |includedFlag|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|[2019-11-11 20:08:47, 2020-10-15 20:08:47, 2021-09-19 20:08:47]|true        |
|[2017-11-05 20:08:47, 2020-05-05 20:08:47, 2021-11-11 20:08:47]|false       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: In what way is this related to pyspark? Can you share more of your code? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: It's a pyspark dataframe.

Comment: Please add the output of `df.printSchema()` to your question. Can you use Spark >= 2.4?

Comment: The output of df.printSchema() is 
root
 |-- dateTimeValue: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: timestamp (containsNull = true)
And I can use spark >=2.4

Comment: On top of the output of `df.printSchema()`, can we get some actual [code and test data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I don't know how we are expected to help otherwise.

Comment: ```
import datetime
df = spark.createDataFrame([([datetime.datetime(2019,11,11,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2020,10,15,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2021,9,19,20,8,47)],), ([datetime.datetime(2017,11,5,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2020,5,5,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2021,11,11,20,8,47)],)], ['dateTimeValue'])
```

Comment: This is the input dataframe

Answer (score 0):

With [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) you can create a new row for each element of your array and compare each single element with the boundaries of your range.

```py
import datetime 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([([datetime.datetime(2019,11,11,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2020,10,15,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2021,9,19,20,8,47)],), ([datetime.datetime(2017,11,5,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2020,5,5,20,8,47), datetime.datetime(2021,11,11,20,8,47)],)], ['dateTimeValue'])
df.show(truncate=False)

df= df.withColumn('ex', F.explode('dateTimeValue'))
df= df.withColumn('includedFlag', F.when((F.col('ex') < datetime.datetime(2019,12,8,00,00,00)) & (F.col("ex") > datetime.datetime(2018,8,8,00,00,00)) , 1).otherwise(0))
df.groupby('dateTimeValue').agg(F.max('includedFlag').alias('includedFlag')).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|dateTimeValue                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2019-11-11 20:08:47, 2020-10-15 20:08:47, 2021-09-19 20:08:47]|
|[2017-11-05 20:08:47, 2020-05-05 20:08:47, 2021-11-11 20:08:47]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|dateTimeValue                                                  |includedFlag|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|[2017-11-05 20:08:47, 2020-05-05 20:08:47, 2021-11-11 20:08:47]|0           |
|[2019-11-11 20:08:47, 2020-10-15 20:08:47, 2021-09-19 20:08:47]|1           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```